# Error when trying to use WUA remotely with C#

Tags: c#, connection, updates, windows-update

I want to use WUA remotly to check several server for updates, so that i can update them all with my program (which will save me a lot of time). I saw several solutions like this:

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session", "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
UpdateSession session = (UpdateSession)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
IUpdateSearcher updateSearcher = session.CreateUpdateSearcher();
int count = updateSearcher.GetTotalHistoryCount();
IUpdateHistoryEntryCollection history = updateSearcher.QueryHistory(0, count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Title: {0}\tDate: {1}\r\n", history[i].Title, history[i].Date));
```

But as soon i try to *(UpdateSession)Activator.CreateInstance(t);* i get an COMException. I also question this solution because if i want to connect remoly i normally must have a username, a password and a servername.

Comment: It seems like the ip-address from `Type.GetTypreFromProgID` is the adress from the Hostname of a WSUS-server and not and ip-address of a system you want to check for updates. As far as i see it by now, there is no "easy" way to check a list of servers remotely for updates. I will try it with WMI.